# S3Client vs S3AsyncClient

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, netty, aws-billing

I'm working on AWS Lambda with the java SDK provided by AWS. I need to get an object from an S3 bucket.
I use an S3Client for it (with apache HTTP as custom configuration)
Times are acceptable.

Now I'm looking to replace my S3Client by an S3AsyncClient (netty).
I use custom configuration as explained in the AWS documentation.

I ve defined a StopWatch to count the full lambda processing time.
I can see some improvement :

total time: 254.4 ms (from my StopWatch)

BUT AWS adds +/- 2250 ms of billing time!

16:34:22
END RequestId: 3a8a2313-f3c7-4933-85a3-2f18e8876364
16:34:22
REPORT RequestId: 3a8a2313-f3c7-4933-85a3-2f18e8876364 Duration: 2460.98 ms Billed Duration: 2500 ms

So I pay a lot more!

Where does this difference come from?
I think that some netty/executor threads keep in WAITING STATE for while then AWS kills them ... But not sure about it ...

I have configured my executor service.
At the end for my lambda I try to stop all threads by using an executor.shutdown();
But It doesn't change anything...

As S3AsyncClient the extends AutoCloseable I 've defined it in a try with resources statement.

I precise that it occurs at both cold / hot start.

Need some help to understand this behaviour ...?

Thank you